# Store data to database using GET via $.ajax()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

I want to save some `GET` to my database using `$.ajax()` but the data only returns empty. Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'file.php?data=',
    type: 'GET',

    data: {
        f: $('input[name="textfield"]').val(),
        c: $('#coordinates').html(),
        a: $('#address').html()
    },

    success: function(s) {
        console.log(s);
    }
});
```

The PHP part look like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['data'])) {
    echo $_GET['f'].' - '.$_GET['c'].' - '.$_GET['a'];
}
```

This code only returns `--`. What have I missed?

**Update**
The link from the network tab in developer tools in Chrome, shows as follows: `http://.../send/data?f=hello&c=62.3875%2C+16.325556&a=KLOCKEN+520%2C+840+13+Tor‌​pshammar%2C+Sverige` (`send/data` is `file.php?data=`). But when I replace `echo $_GET['f']...` with `var_dump($_GET)` it prints the following:

```
array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Why can't I get the data from `$_GET['f']`, `$_GET['c']`, and `$_GET['a']` with the code above?

Comment: are you sure some data is submitted to the sever.... inspect the request using the browser's network tab(developer tools) to see what data is submitted

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the network tab in developer tools. I can there see that the request sends `[object FormData]` to the selected file. Stupid question, but are my data in JSON with the code in my question?

Comment: Where do you see that? You should be looking at the URL parameters, it should be something like `file.php?data=&f=something&c=another&a=somethingElse`

Comment: it looks like you are inspecting a wrong request....

Comment: @Barmar Here's the full link with the main link censured: `http://.../send/data?[object%20FormData]&_=1422333882608`. `send/data` is `file.php?data=`.

Comment: I don't see any way that could come from this AJAX request. jQuery doesn't create `FormData` requests, you need to use something like jQuery Form Plugin for that.

Comment: @ErikEdgren then there is something wrong in your code... look at [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8yb24rs9/1/) the proper data is sent

Comment: @ArunPJohny Many thanks! I did see my mistake (I forgot to remove `data: new FormData($('#manual')[0])` from the request) and now it's working. But now I can't get the data from `GET`, even if it's exists there. It doesn't see my data requests from `$.ajax()`. Only `?data=`.

Comment: now what is the url that is shown in the network tab

Comment: @ArunPJohny `http://.../send/data?f=hello&c=62.3875%2C+16.325556&a=KLOCKEN+520%2C+840+13+Torpshammar%2C+Sverige`. But if I add `var_dump($_GET);` in `file.php?data=` it only prints `array(1) { ["data"]=>string(0) "" }`

Comment: @ErikEdgren that url looks fine... with proper data being sent... as for PHP not sure(not an expert in that...)

Comment: True. That's too bad :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS should be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "file.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: ...
});
```

You don't need the extra `?data=` as part of the URL. That will be generated for you by jQuery. With it, you are overriding your GET request. So, you can see from the URL you posted, you posted a key "data" with no value, so your vardump is indeed showing you a key "data" with no value.

Your PHP should be:

```
if(isset($_GET['f']) && isset($_GET['c']) && isset($_GET['a'])) {
    echo $_GET['f'].' - '.$_GET['c'].' - '.$_GET['a'];
}
```

"data" is just the parameter of the jQuery AJAX call - it isn't actually the name of your object.

You asked about JSON in a comment. Right now, all your data is being sent URL-encoded. To send JSON, a way to do it is:

```
var submitPackage = {
    f: JSON.stringify($('input[name="textfield"]').val()),
    c: JSON.stringify($('#coordinates').html()),
    a: JSON.stringify($('#address').html())
};

$.ajax({
    url: "file.php",
    type: "GET", //Is there a reason you care about doing GET versus POST (the default)?
    data: submitPackage
});
```

Then your PHP would be:

```
if(isset($_GET['f']) && isset($_GET['c']) && isset($_GET['a'])) {
    echo json_decode($_GET['f']) . ' - ' . json_decode($_GET['c']) . ' - ' . json_decode($_GET['a']);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm getting the same problem with your possible solution: returning empty :/

Comment: @ErikEdgren out of curiosity, could you please try changing all the `$_GET` to `$_REQUEST` This will test to make sure your variables are actually being treated as a GET (which they should be, based on the jQuery request and the URL you showed, but it's worth checking to make sure.).

Comment: My PHP code besides that I already showed, is basically the same as I showed - a lot of `GET`. So there's nothing more too see. I'm getting the same result with `$_REQUEST` as for `$_GET` - just empty :(

Comment: @ErikEdgren I updated my answer. Your `$.ajax` request is wrong. I have the fixed version in my answer (and you will still need to make the PHP changes I suggested, though the JSON part is not required).